# Access app.yml file in library class variable

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a class in which i am keeping some constant variables. I want to assign a value from app.yml into a class variable there but it is giving syntax error for that. Following is the code snippet:

```
class StaticPhotoUrls  
{      
const abc = sfConfig::get("app_myvalue");   
}
```

Comment: This code looks ok. Can you paste the exact error message and line of code the error message refers? Keep in mind also that using the app.yml parameters is application specific - unless you define them in the main config folder.

Comment: parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call."

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define a `constant` by a function or something different than plain value.

Instead, you should use `define()` to be able to set the value from your app.yml:

```
define('abc', sfConfig::get("app_myvalue"));
```

But what do you want to use a constant?

Comment: So that i dont need to create any objects while using them